# Should we increase the reputation points for editing/ quality of edit?

Tags: discussion

So,  I read this [thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13104/should-proper-english-matter) and I'm personally on the side that we should try to see what the user is actually is trying to say instead of focusing over lenses on the grammar of the post. Now with that in mind, I've recently become contributing to this site by editing and fixing questions to uphold them to a higher quality standard. By no means is my English perfect, but, I try my best.

Keeping all of that in mind, I feel rather unrewarded even if I spend a while editing a question to make it look much more nicer. As in, there is not enough reputation given for quality of edit, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that no matter how much you edited, the amount of reputation points is ultimately the same.

I'm okay with being an altruist with the editing but I think I should have some sort of indicator that my editing is seen as valuable to the site, unless of course, this site doesn't actually value people sending time to edit and fix questions.

To be frank, I really have nothing conclusive to say, and I wish for more viewpoints and the overall opinion of this community on this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think I should have some sort of indicator that my editing is seen as valuable to the site, unless of course, this site doesn't actually value people sending time to edit and fix questions.

There are many things one can do that are valuable to the site that don't give you reputation, for example leaving useful comments, spending time in the various queues, flagging/voting to close poor content, participating in the meta site, etc. Some of these things do give you badges eventually, so there is still at least some indicator that you have done these things.

Reputation doesn't mean "value to the site". It primary means "value to the questions and answers". Which I suppose is why you get some reputation for getting edits approved, but edits shouldn't be a substantial source of reputation.

Answer (score 5):

As a Q&A site it makes sense that the fastest way to earn reputation is by asking and answering good questions. Note that once you hit 2,000 reputation you will stop receiving reputation points for edits anyway since your edits no longer require approval.